# SQL Query to display employee who is a supervisor from employee table

Tags: mysql, sql-server, select

I am in this dilemma: here is a table with records.

The last column has supervisors and it refers to the first column.

How can I select all employees who are supervisors and display for each, first name and last name?

Here is the table

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` to do this(preferred approach)

```
SELECT *
FROM   yourtable t1
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   yourtable t2
               WHERE  t1.EMPLOYEEID = t2.EMPSUPERVISOR)
```

using `IN` operator

```
SELECT *
FROM   yourtable t1
WHERE  t1.EMPLOYEEID IN (SELECT t2.EMPSUPERVISOR
                         FROM   yourtable t2)
```

using `JOIN`

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM   yourtable t1
       JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT EMPSUPERVISOR
             FROM   yourtable) t2
         ON t1.EMPLOYEEID = t2.EMPSUPERVISOR
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

```
 SELECT EMPLNAME , EMPLFNAME 
   FROM THETABLE
  WHERE EMPLOEEID IN (SELECT DISTINCT EMPSUPERVISOR
                        FROM THETABLE
                     )
 ;
```